# Spring MVC binding a JSP to a bean's 'double' property gives output on JSP page as '0.0'. How to keep it blank?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Suppose i have a bean

```
Class A{
 private double d;
     //Getter and setter methods
}
```

Now if i bind these fields to jsp

```
<form:input path = "d"/>
```

In the JSP page i get an input field pre-populated as "0.0" . I know these is because it represents the default value for double which is "0.0".

But what if i dont want the values to be prepopulated.

In short do not show default value but show calculated ones example 4.5 or -9.4  etc. Is it possible? If yes how ?

Comment: did u try declaring the property as Double?

Comment: Does the job thanks a lot